# How to get in the new column after height of parent exceeds

Tags: html, css

I am struggling with columns and rows and cannot get it to work, here is the example of what I need:

[image]

Here is the css I have:

```
ul.people {
 position: absolute;
 width: 900px;
 height: 640px;
 top: 450px;
 right: 318px;
 list-style: none;
 overflow: hidden;
}

li.man-red {
 width: 45px;
 height: 132px;
 background: url(../img/man_red.png) no-repeat;
 background-position: 3px 5px;
}
```

So, I need that every fifth `li` element goes into a new column.

Comment: unclear to me what you're asking

Comment: I have javascript and you can add/remove this people... Its perfectly working if I set `float: left` to `li` element, but I want that people are orderded from top to bottom and when height is exceeded to get in new row.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to come up with some clever stuff using:

- `float:left;`
- relative positioning using `top` & `left` co-ordinates
- negative `margin-left`

**Example:**

```css
li.man-red {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 width: 45px;
 height: 132px;
 margin: 1px;
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: bold;
 background: url(../img/man_red.png) no-repeat #f00;
 background-position: 3px 5px;
 list-style-type: none;
}


li.man-red:nth-of-type(4n+1) {
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

li.man-red:nth-of-type(4n+2) {
top: 134px;
left: -47px;
}

li.man-red:nth-of-type(4n+3) {
top: 268px;
left: -94px;
}

li.man-red:nth-of-type(4n+4) {
top: 402px;
left: -141px;
}

li.man-red:nth-of-type(4n+5) {
margin-left: -140px;
}

li.man-red:nth-of-type(4n+6) {
margin-left: -93px;
}

li.man-red:nth-of-type(4n+7) {
margin-left: -46px;
}

li.man-red:nth-of-type(4n+8) {
margin-left: 1px;
}
```

```html
<ul>

<li class="man-red">1</li>
<li class="man-red">2</li>
<li class="man-red">3</li>
<li class="man-red">4</li>

<li class="man-red">5</li>
<li class="man-red">6</li>
<li class="man-red">7</li>
<li class="man-red">8</li>

<li class="man-red">9</li>
<li class="man-red">10</li>
<li class="man-red">11</li>
<li class="man-red">12</li>

<li class="man-red">13</li>
<li class="man-red">14</li>
<li class="man-red">15</li>
<li class="man-red">16</li>

<li class="man-red">17</li>
<li class="man-red">18</li>
<li class="man-red">19</li>
<li class="man-red">20</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: if you are using `float:left` then `display:inline-block` is not doing anything there

Comment: Thanks for a quick response, but I need to order them from top to bottom and then in new row when height is exceeded.

Comment: @dippas - wow. You're so right. I've been doing that instinctively for years - it might date back to an IE6-compatibility hack or something - and never really thought about it. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @Rounin no problem, Ya I remember the headaches of IE6 and IE7

Comment: @Rounin for example: when I add 5 li elements (5x 132px) the height is same as parent div have. Then I need that the sixth li element goes in new row.

Comment: In a new row or in a new column?

Comment: I think I've cracked it. See my revised post above.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this you are trying to achieve? Adding groups of 5 `li` in each `ul`

#### Snippet

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  background:lightblue;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.figure {
  width: 45px;
  height: 132px;
  margin: 1px;
  background: url(//lorempixel.com/45/132) no-repeat red;
  background-position: 3px 5px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="figure"></li>
  <li class="figure"></li>
  <li class="figure"></li>
  <li class="figure"></li>
  <li class="figure"></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="figure"></li>
  <li class="figure"></li>
  <li class="figure"></li>
  <li class="figure"></li>
  <li class="figure"></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="figure"></li>
  <li class="figure"></li>
  <li class="figure"></li>
  <li class="figure"></li>
  <li class="figure"></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="figure"></li>
  <li class="figure"></li>
  <li class="figure"></li>
  <li class="figure"></li>
  <li class="figure"></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="figure"></li>
  <li class="figure"></li>
  <li class="figure"></li>
  <li class="figure"></li>
  <li class="figure"></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="figure"></li>
  <li class="figure"></li>
  <li class="figure"></li>
  <li class="figure"></li>
  <li class="figure"></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="figure"></li>
  <li class="figure"></li>
  <li class="figure"></li>
  <li class="figure"></li>
  <li class="figure"></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="figure"></li>
  <li class="figure"></li>
  <li class="figure"></li>
  <li class="figure"></li>
  <li class="figure"></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="figure"></li>
  <li class="figure"></li>
  <li class="figure"></li>
  <li class="figure"></li>
  <li class="figure"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That would be okay, but I don't want to modify javascript for adding new `ul` for every fifth item. Is it possible to do that with pure CSS?

Comment: let me test it, and see what I can do with just pure CSS

Comment: I can't see at the moment a way to do this besides the one I gave you in my answer.

Comment: Yes, its tricky. I will do it with js then. If you find an answer maybe please update the answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I  really don't see any other way of doing this without changing your current HTML markup, not even using pseudo selectors. I've been thinking but can't figure it out. Would be a good question for a bounty (CSS only without changing HTML markup)

Comment: I think I might have cracked it. See my revised post above.

Comment: @Rounin Ya like sprite images, that cross my mind but as would be dynamic I disregard at the time.  just forgot that the images had fixed width and height. Upvoted yours.

Comment: please check my answer if you have anything to add

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, I set this styles and it actually works:

```
ul.people {
  position: absolute;
  width: 900px;
  height: 640px;
  top: 450px;
  right: 318px;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-columns: 20;
  -moz-columns: 20;
  columns: 20;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0; 
  -moz-column-gap: 0; 
  column-gap: 0;
  -webkit-column-rule: 0; 
  -moz-column-rule: 0; 
  column-rule: 0;
}

li.man-red {
  width: 45px;
  height: 132px;
  background: url(../img/man_red.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: 3px 5px;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Comment: careful with `page-break` because it is not yet  supported using `avoid` - [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=page-break)